# How to run a diffrent method each time a new comboboxItem has been selected

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi there just building a small conversion calculator and Im adding a combo box to it so its not as cluttered and easy to manage. I wont to add a few options to my combo box so that the user has different options to choose from. However I'am going to build a small class with the conversion calculations so that when a different option is selected within the combo box the correct method will be called. I will add a code snippet to show use were i'am at. I was just using the message box just so i know that it was working. Any code snippets would be great.

```
private void comboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   ComboBoxItem kilo = ((sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem);
}

private double workOutKilo()
{
   double result = 2;
   return result;
}
```

Comment: are you looking for a `switch` block?

Comment: Yes that would be good.

Answer (score 2):

Assign each ComboBoxItem's Tag control a function, within the SelectionChanged event, call the function.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah if you use a switch than it might be easy to choose combined by the code you already have.

I would suggest something like this:

```
private void comboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBoxItem kilo = ((sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem);

        switch (kilo.ToString())
        {
            case "Kilo":
                //Method();
                break;
            //...
        }
    }
```

I guess this would do the job:

```
private void comboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox kilo = (sender as ComboBox);
        int index = kilo.SelectedIndex;

        switch (kilo.ToString())
        {
            case "0":
                //Method();
                break;
            //...
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do I tie up each comboBoxItem with a specific case ? my comboBoxItems have no names.

Comment: You could also chose to use a selectedindex and use that to get a specific case. It would be of course a number starting from 0. I hope this will be helpfull to you.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far its greatly appreciated. I was wondering if you dont mind could u show me a code snippet ?